# Using OAuth2.0 in Python Script on OpenMediaVault

Tags: oauth-2.0, spotify, openmediavault

I am not sure wether this is the right form and i am pretty new to this stuff, so please bear with me...

Currently, I am trying to automate a few things in my home. One thing is related to Spotify.
To do that i wrote a python script, which works good on my laptop, but when I transfer it over to my NAS-Server (OpenMediaVault6) the script doesn't work. I want it there for task scheduling.

I think I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
In the python script I have to get an access token from spotify. For that I need to authenticate myself in a browser, but on a NAS-Server that is not possible as far as I know.

I tried to solve it with a Client Credentials Flow, but I need to access my user information.

This is a simplified code:

```
import spotipy


CLIENT_ID = "client_id"
CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret"
REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8888/callback"
USER_ID = "user_id"
SCOPE = "user-read-private user-read-email"

token = spotipy.util.prompt_for_user_token(USER_ID, SCOPE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI)

print(token)
```

Does anyone have a smart idea how to get this running on the NAS?

Thansk in advance.

Comment: You can copy the .cache file to the folder/directory you want to run the script from. (Sometimes, that's not the same directory you placed the script in.)

Comment: @Ximzend: Thank you for the suggestions, buut doesn't the cache only save the current token with the expiration time? I guess it will work for 1-2h but not longer. Or am I wrong there? 
I will certainly try it :)

Comment: It also stores a Refresh Token to refresh the access token after that one hour.

Comment: @Ximzend: Thank you, I managed to make it work and posted an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future refernce (Solution motivated by @Ximzend):

Apparently is the `Refresh Token`, which is provided with the `Access Token`, vaild until revoken from the user.
So one can access the `Cache`, where both and the time for the `Access Token` to expire is saved and generate a new `Access Token` without having to authorize again.
So basically, generate the `Access Token` once on a normal PC/System and then copy the `Cache` to the NAS-Server such that this Script can access it.

It's something like that then:

```
import json
import requests
import base64

CLIENT_ID = "client_id"
CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret"

with open(".cache-<user_id>", 'r') as cach:
    data = cach.read()
cache = json.loads(data)

REFRESH_TOKEN = cache['refresh_token']

def get_new_token():
    authorization = base64.b64encode(bytes(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET, "ISO-8859-1")).decode("ascii")

    endpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {authorization}",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {
        "refresh_token": REFRESH_TOKEN,
        "grant_type": "refresh_token"
    }

    response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=data)

    return response.json()["access_token"]

ACCESS_TOKEN = get_new_token()
```

I am running that code daily on my NAS and sending myself the new `Access Token` per Report to my Mail, just to check, wether it's still working so that my other scripts, which depend on the token and run weekly, can still work.